# How do I use the $and Logical Query Operator to apply to all three Query clauses?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Though I am using the `$and` Logical Query Operator to join several query clauses, the `$and` logical query operator seems to **IGNORE** one of the query clauses. Can someone kindly explain where I am going wrong in my query?

Find below the relevant content of the document in subject `recipientsDetails.find({}).fetch();`:

```
0
payersNumber: "+254700027685"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"

1
payersNumber: "+254700007633"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"

2
payersNumber: "+254700007633"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"
```

When the query below (joined together by the `$and` Logical Query Operator) is run, it seems to omit the `{payersNumber: { $ne: usersPhoneNumber } }` clause.

```
var userIdCode = Meteor.userId(); 
var phoneNumber = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userIdCode }, { fields: { "profile.telephoneNumber": 1 } } ); 
var usersPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.profile.telephoneNumber; 

recipientsDetails.find( { $and: [ { payersNumber: usersPhoneNumber }, 
                                  { recipientNumber: usersPhoneNumber }, 
                                  { payersNumber: { $ne: usersPhoneNumber } }  
                                ] }).fetch();
```

Because of the ignored query clause, the query above yields:

```
0
payersNumber: "+254700007633"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"

1
payersNumber: "+254700007633"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"
```

Instead of:

```
0
payersNumber: "+254700027685"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"

1
payersNumber: "+254700007633"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"

2
payersNumber: "+254700007633"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"
```

Can someone kindly explain why this is happening, and how to correct my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the rules you specified in the comments below (assuming I understood them correctly), can be normalised to -> "Return all documents where I am the payer or receiver".

```
recipientsDetails.find( { $or: [ { payersNumber: usersPhoneNumber }, 
                                  { recipientNumber: usersPhoneNumber } 
                                ] }).fetch();
```

This should return documents where the `usersPhoneNumber` is either the recipient or payer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however your solution does not work. Changing to the query you suggested, the query now only yields:                                 
`0
payersNumber: "+254700027685"
recipientNumber: "+254700007633"`

Comment: @SirBT If I understood it correctly, you'd like to return based on 'recipientNumber' alone. Try the updated code. Otherwise, what's the logic you're after?

Comment: To explain the logic behind it, the collective clauses document is supposed to reflect a mobile money transaction statement where **my number** `usersPhoneNumber` is:  1. the sender of the money to any random number `recipientNumber` ,                                2. both the sender and the recipient `recipientNumber`,                                                                                                  
3. the recipient of money, from a random number `payersNumber` apart from mine `usersPhoneNumber`. I hope this has given you some clarity on the logic behind it?

Comment: Yes your query solution works perfectly, though logically it doesn't make any sense why it would! I thought the most logical operation to used here would be $AND. Can you kindly explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Given you were looking for a single query that 'met any' of the 3 conditions provided, `$or` was the most fitting operator (i.e. meet any = `$or`, meet all = `$and`).

Comment: Pure Genius! Have you got some time look at this query sorting issue that I am having [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630430/why-isnt-my-sort-operator-on-dates-function-consistent-in-my-query]