# Why isn't my $sort Operator on dates function consistent in my query?

Tags: sorting, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a query to sort out documents based on descending dates `...{sort: {paymentDate: -1 }}` order. The first time the query runs, the query section `{sort: {paymentDate: -1 }}` seems get ignored!
However when I refresh the page in the browser, the **query section** `{sort: {paymentDate: -1 }}` is applied, and the query displays in the correct **sort** order.

I need to know how to correct this issue!

Find below the contents of my document after I run the `recipientsDetails.find().fetch();` query in the browser console:

```
0:
payersUserId: "hbieZBFNE53GpE8LP"
paymentDate: "2019-02-11 02:37:05"
payersNumber: "+25478887633"
paymentStatus: "Failed"
recipientNumber: "+25478887633"
_id: "eFShDRzp9JM9ejG5S"

1:
payersUserId: "hbieZBFNE53GpE8LP"
paymentDate: "2019-02-08 16:02:25"
payersNumber: "+2547078887633"
paymentStatus: "Failed"
recipientNumber: "+25478887633"
_id: "SnpNwsx49mZfPNSg7"

2:
payersUserId: "hbieZBFNE53GpE8LP"
paymentDate: "2019-02-08 15:00:02"
payersNumber: "+254707888633"
paymentStatus: "Failed"
recipientNumber: "+25478087703"
_id: "ZHWSiRBYk2xoZvDzb"
```

The above results is also the desired sorted order.

Perhaps the below **helper** code might shade some light.

**../client/main.js**

```
Template.paymentB2C.helpers({

'enableButton': function () {

    var enableButtonStatusArray = [];   
    var userIdCode = Meteor.userId(); 
    var phoneNumber = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userIdCode }, { fields: { "profile.telephoneNumber": 1 } } ); 
    var usersPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.profile.telephoneNumber; 

    var selectedRecipientDetails = recipientsDetails.find( { $or: [ { payersNumber: usersPhoneNumber }, { recipientNumber: usersPhoneNumber } ] }, 

                                            { fields: { 
                                                        "payersUserId": 1,
                                                        "paymentDate": 1,
                                                        "paymentStatus": 1,
                                                        "_id": 1

                                            } }).fetch();


         selectedRecipientDetails.forEach((user) => {
                    payersUserId = user.payersUserId;
                    paymentDate = user.paymentDate;
                    paymentStatus = user.paymentStatus;
                    _id = user._id;

                if(paymentStatus === "Failed"){

                        enableButtonStatusArray.push({ 
                            paymentStatus: paymentStatus,
                            paymentDate: paymentDate,
                            _id: _id
                            });

                    }

            else if(paymentStatus === "Passed"){

                        enableButtonStatusArray.push({ 
                            paymentStatus: paymentStatus,
                            paymentDate: paymentDate,
                            _id: _id});

                   }

            Session.set('enableButtonStatusArray2', enableButtonStatusArray );

        });

    var enableButtonStatusArrayForPrint = Session.get('enableButtonStatusArray2');

return enableButtonStatusArrayForPrint;

}


});
```

Note that the query here lacks a `...{sort: {paymentDate: -1 }}` function.

Find below my `Router` code:

../client/main.js

```
Router.route('/paymentB2C', {
name: 'paymentB2C',  
template: 'paymentB2C',

    waitOn: function(){

       return Meteor.subscribe('pendingPayments')

    }
```

});

This leads to my `Meteor.subscribe('pendingPayments')` publish function:

**../server/main.js**

```
Meteor.publish('pendingPayments', function pendingPayments(){

   return recipientsDetails.find({}, {sort: {paymentDate: -1 }});

});
```

Note that here is where I have the `sort` function.

Can someone explain why when codes first runs, the **sort** is ignored and the the document is randomly sorted, however is sorted out as designed (correctly) after hitting refresh in the browser?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Did you check if paymentDate field is subscribed?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should sort the data on the client-side query after you subscribe, instead of sorting it in the publish method.

The reason is that if the client subscribes to more than one publish function which will publish data from the same collections, your `find` query in the client-side will have access to the data from both publish as well as sort won't be effective. Moreover, publish is something which will grant data access to the subscriber and if the mini-mongo on the client side already has the data, it won't sync the data unless new data arrives.

Hence, you should always do sort and filter in your `find` queries on the client side as well.

Also, I notice that the format of the `paymentDate` field is not a 'Date'. It should ideally be of the `Date` format and should look something like `ISODate("2019-02-11T02:37:05.000Z")` instead of `String` format `"2019-02-11 02:37:05"`. So if the sorting on the client side is also not working, try saving the `paymentDate` in the database as `Date` instead as a `String`.